# How to check if a folder has no files locked by any process?

Tags: powershell, process, file-locking

I am trying to write a `PowerShell` script that will check if none of the files in a particular folder is locked by any process; if true, only then delete the folder.

One way is to check locks on each file by opening them in RW mode iteratively - see if exception occurs. But that's too cumbersome.

Is there a way to check the same thing for a folder? I tried to use `Remove-Item` with `-WhatIf` flag but it's of no use because the command doesn't return any value - nor did it detect the locked files. If I try to run `Remove-Item` without the flag to look for exception, then it removes the free files only whereas I want to have a All or None condition.

Comment: You can always get the Restart Manager to check the locks for you, but it's still somewhat cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're not going to distribute the solution, you could use [handle.exe](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/handle.aspx). It shows all files/folders in use and who is using it.

```
$path = "C:\Users\frode\Desktop\Test folder"

(.\handle64.exe /accepteula $path /nobanner) -match 'File'
explorer.exe       pid: 1888   type: File           F3C: C:\Users\frode\Desktop\Test folder
explorer.exe       pid: 1888   type: File          2E54: C:\Users\frode\Desktop\Test folder
notepad.exe        pid: 2788   type: File            38: C:\Users\frode\Desktop\Test folder
WINWORD.EXE        pid: 2780   type: File            40: C:\Users\frode\Desktop\Test folder
WINWORD.EXE        pid: 2780   type: File           6FC: C:\Users\frode\Desktop\Test folder\New Microsoft Word-dokument.docx
```

If you only want a yes/no answer you can use an if-test and `-match` to see it if returns any results.

```
if((.\handle64.exe /accepteula $path /nobanner) -match 'File') { "IN USE, ABORT MISSION!" }
```

Usually you're able to delete a folder even if `explorer.exe` is browsing inside it, so you could usually exclude that process from the results:

```
if((.\handle64.exe /accepteula $path /nobanner) -match 'File' -notmatch 'explorer.exe') { "IN USE, ABORT MISSION!" }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't wanna install handle, you can look wich process is running in the given directory or subdirectory.

```
$lockedFolder="C:\Windows\System32" 
Get-Process | % {
  $processVar = $_
  $_.Modules | %{ 
    if($_.FileName -like "$lockedFolder*"){
        $processVar.Name + " PID:" + $processVar.id + " FullName: " + $_.FileName 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work on a directory where a file is locked by an external process not running from that same directory (like excel opening a sheet - the directory is locked but excel is not running in that directory)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete solution, but is a starting point, on which you can build.

I have a txt file called "demo.txt" under: "E:\Work\Powershell\scripts\demo". And I am using Notepad.exe to open it. In this case, I will not be able to delete the folder "demo", until I close the notepad.

You will have to query the **"Win32_process"** class to understand, if the notepad is using the file.

```
Get-WmiObject win32_process | where {$_.name -eq 'notepad.exe'}
```

In the output of the above cmdlet, the **"CommandLine"** property, will show you what files are currently being used by that process.

[image]

You may have to iterate over this to have a complete solution for your problem.

Certain processes like - "chrome.exe" will have a huge listing under "CommandLine" property, Since chrome or iExplorer will not prevent you to delete the folder when they have the file opened, you may ignore those kind of processes.

Note: The "FileName" under "(Get-Process).Modules", provides you only the PATH where you can find "notepad.exe" (i.e., E:\Work\Powershell\scripts\demo )

Comment: This should pretty much work:

$location = 'E:\Work\Powershell\scripts\demo'
Get-WmiObject Win32_process | where {$_.commandline -like "*$location*"} | select name

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just attempt to rename-item on the $path and if it fails it has a lock on it. Throw a little try{ catch{ in there and you get something maybe like below. Nice and Simple

```
#check for locking handle    
Function Check-LockedItem {
        param([string]$path)
        $name = Split-Path "$path" -leaf
        $pathorg = Split-Path "$path" -Parent
        try {Rename-Item -Path "$path" -NewName "$name--" -ErrorAction Stop}
        catch {write-host "A process is locking $path. Please close the process and try again"}
        Finally {Rename-Item -path "$pathorg\$name--" -NewName $name -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
}
```

Usage

```
Check-LockedItem -Path "C:\Mypathtotest"
```